# cURL use to download a file when site requires login

Tags: curl

cURL use to download a file when site requires login
struggling with syntax, chrome tools show this:

```
curl "https://retailerservices.diamondcomics.com/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=^%^2fHome^%^2fIndex" 
   -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" 
   -H "Origin: https://retailerservices.diamondcomics.com" 
   -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" 
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
   -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" 
   -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" 
   -H "Referer: https://retailerservices.diamondcomics.com/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=^%^2fHome^%^2fIndex" 
   -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" 
   -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" 
   -H "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.50460841.1551927155; _gid=GA1.2.740108162.1551927155; __qca=P0-1882114835-1551927155190; __utma=50487996.50460841.1551927155.1551927198.1551927198.1; __utmc=50487996; __utmz=50487996.1551927198.1.1.utmcsr=retailer.diamondcomics.com^|utmccn=(referral)^|utmcmd=referral^|utmcct=/Home/1/1/28/225; __utmt=1; ASP.NET_SessionId=vroayxspzan2wllbmwnqrj3s; SERVERID=ckypr2^|XICJp^|XICHn; __utmb=50487996.6.10.1551927198"
   --data "UserName=XXXXXXX^&EnteredCustNo=^&Password=XXXXX^&RememberMe=false^&Submit=Login" --compressed
```

error indicated `--compressed` would not work, remove compressed
then
see this

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you edit your question to be more specific? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am trying to use cURL from a command line to login to a web site and then download a file. The login page is a separate page.